# append 0 returned by DATENAME function Sql Server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to append 0 to my minute(mi) result returned by DATENAME function of sql server management studio.

```
select datename(mi,GETDATE())
```

1. If the current time where 12:06:33.12(hh:mi:ss) then '6' would be
   returned by the above query and I want 0 to be prefixed with the
   result i.e '06' only when my minute is less than 10.
2. This can be easily done by branching and checking the result obtained
   by above query and seeing if it is less than 10 i.e using a CASE
   statement.Is there a much cleaner way to do the job without
   branching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), datename(mi,GETDATE())), 2)
```